# Python Win32 Com on Remote Machine SSH

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, win32com

**Objective:**

Hello Currently I am working on Python script with win32com module to run tasks in the windows task scheduler. What I am trying to get is use ssh to runs tasks in task scheduler in remote. ( Remote machine will already have task in task scheduler I just need to run it remotely.

**what I have done**

I am able to do very well with local

```
import win32com.client
 scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
 scheduler.Connect()
 ...

 ...
 task = rootFolder.GetTask(task_id)
 task.Enabled = True
 runningTask = task.Run("") #or enable it to run when scheduled
```

**Question**

If I need to run the task from task ID list in remote machine. Do I ssh to Machine via python and run another python script with parameter including ssh details and task id? or is it possible to connect to remote machine and access it's win32com?